# Symfony Form Event Listener для коллекций

Tags: symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Мучаюсь уже третий день и не могу понять, как применить слушателей событий форм к коллекциям. Данные меняются динамически в зависимости от ввода пользователя. Форма содержит коллекцию с данными в которых пользователь и заполняет поля. Для того, чтобы изменять данные динамически, я использую события `POST_SET` и `PRE_SUBMIT` при этом `POST_SET` работает на ура, а вот с событиями после отправки формы беда.

В событии `PRE_SUBMIT` я в цикле прохожусь по всем коллекциям формы и получаю поля коллекции, которые я могу изменять. Только вот проблема в том, что во время иcпользования коллекций их инициализация происходит во время события `SUBMIT`, то есть в `PRE_SUBMIT` их просто еще нет в форме! А если использовать для изменения события `SUBMIT` или `POST_SUBMIT`, тогда коллекция уже есть в форме, но изменить ее уже нельзя, так как на это этапе она уже инициализирована.

Поэтому получается замкнутый круг, в `PRE_SUBMIT` данные коллекции можно изменить но их там еще нет, а в `SUBMIT` они есть, но изменить их уже нельзя. Пример кода для наглядности:

```
public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // We don`t need to change locations in add event only for update existed
    $client = $form->getConfig()->getOptions()['client'];

    $shareForms = $form->get('shares');

    foreach ($data['shares'] as $key => $share) {
        if ($share['pickUpDay'] !== null && $share['pickUpDay'] !== '') {
            $locations = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member\Location')->getLocationsByDay($client, $share['pickUpDay']);
            $this->addLocationField($shareForms->get($key), $locations);
        }
    }
}
```

Получить экземпляр коллекции в `preSubmit` методом `$shareForms->get($key)` я не могу, а в `postSubmit` могу, но там поля уже менять нельзя. Может у кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым и логичным. При возникновении необходимости менять и устанавливать значения для экземпляров коллекции, слушателей нужно назначать не на родительскую форму, а непосредственно на форму-экземпляр коллекции.

Иными словами если у нас есть форма с коллекцией:

```
class MemberType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'entry_type' => AddressType::class,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Valid()
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

Слушателя мы назначаем не здесь, а прямо в классе формы, который указан в entry_type:

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    private $locationListener;

    public function __construct(LocationSubscriber $subscriber)
    {
        $this->locationListener = $subscriber;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Country',
                'query_builder' => function (CountryRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'required' => false
            ]);

        $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->locationListener);
    }
```

Таким образом, события на экземплярах коллекции будет срабатывать автоматически, и никаких циклов не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Ивенты и придназначены для изменения данных.
Попробуйте поментяь так:
$event->setData();

Comment: Попробуйте дать более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: @Yevgeniy это не то, что нужно, в PRE_SET еще нет объектов, только массивы и мне нужно изменить не выбранное значение и сами варианты выбора, то есть поля формы.

Comment: @Yevgeniy в данном случае я имел ввиду PRE_SUBMIT